# How to find a non-trivial combination of the rows and columns

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Matrix A =\begin{bmatrix}1&2&1&1&2\\0&1&1&1&2\\1&0&1&0&2\\1&2&3&0&1\end{bmatrix}

If possible, how can I find a non-trivial linear combination of the rows equal to 0, as well as a combo of the columns equal to 0. I was thinking for the rows, maybe getting the RREF(A) then multiply that matrix by R1, R2, R3, and R4. Am I doing this correctly? And how would I go about finding the columns?

Comment: Have you heard of Gaussian elimination?

Comment: Yes, that is how I've gotten to the RREF.

Comment: Gaussian elimination shows they're a free system…

Comment: What is a free system?

Comment: Means they are linearly independent equations, or in other words, that there is no non-trivial linear combination of them that equals $0$.

Comment: How do you use Gaussian elimination to show they're a free system?

Comment: If your row reduced echelon form does not contain a row of $0$'s, then they're linearly independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RREF of $A$ is 
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac54 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \frac{-5}4 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \frac34 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \frac52  \end{bmatrix}
$$

This shows that the  rows are linearly independent, and the fifth column $C_5$ is a linear combination of $C_1$, $\ldots$, $C_4$. Explicitly, 
$$
C_5 = \frac 54 C_1 -\frac54 C_2 + \frac34 C_3 + \frac52 C_4.
$$

Comment: How does it show it is linearly independent if the last column does not have a leading one?

Comment: Then the rows will be linearly dependent. A row that does not have a leading one is a row of all zeros.

Comment: Yes, I meant column not row.

Comment: Ah, my bad. You meant the fourth column, right?

Comment: No, if the 5th column doesn't have a leading one, then there must be a parameter which implies infinite solutions right? And this is not an augmented matrix, just a heads up.

Comment: Yes, I know this is not an augmented matrix. But, this case worked as if we solve the system with 5th column as an augmented column.  If the 5th column doesn't have a leading one, which is the case we have, the fifth column corresponds to a free variable. So, there are infinitely many solutions in $Ax=0$.

Comment: Oohh. OK, so then how do you figure out if there is a non-trivial linear combination of the columns not equal to zero?

Comment: Just as I wrote on the answer. Look for linear dependence relation in RREF. That will give you the same linear dependence relation in the matrix $A$.

Comment: Ok, sweet, I see it now... Thank you so much for your help!!